# cakephp return to form with selected item in list

Tags: forms, list, cakephp

Using latest cakephp v2.3.7. I am struggling to return to a form which has 2 fields [list items] i would like to have selected as default. The form is to upload files, it populates the region and property from the db in list fields [region_id] [property_id]. When submitting the form the very first time, I would like it to remember what region and which property has been used before and return to the form with these 2 set as 'default selected'. I understand that each time I return the list is populated again, but is there a way still to select the last ones used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you properly receive the selected ones in `$this->data['ModelName']['region_id']`, etc, just set them back to the view.

In your controller:

```
$this->set('selectedRegionID', $this->data['ModelName']['region_id']);
```

Then in your view amend the Form select field to look like this:

```
$this->Form->select('Region', array('default' => $selectedRegionID));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am doing something obviously wrong at the moment, I suppose that's the charm of learning. I have started from scratch with a new form and can confirm I can echo the $selectedRegionID and it works a charm. Need to get now sorted why my form in the way it is is not working. Thank you.

Comment: It goes wrong the very first time because it doesn't know $selectedRegionID. Trying to work out how to solve this.

Comment: I thought you'd figure that out yourself :) Just check if the value `isset($this->data['ModelName']['region_id'])` and if not set the variable `$selectedRegionID` to false, else to the value.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me, still a novice but eager to learn, if it is a bit straight on i could do it, but when it comes to these things i am lost. going to try it and will let you know.